# query to Combine all childlist of all parent objects in one collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class structure like

```
public class Child
{
}

public class Parent
{
    public IEnumerable<Child> ListChild { get; set; }
}
```

and have a Test class

```
public class Test
{
    public IEnumerable<Parent> GetMethod()
    {
        List<Parent> collection = new List<Parent>();
        //// added multiple items of collection with childs.

        var allChildren = from c in collection
                              select c.ListChild;
        var childss = allChildren.Select((c) => c.Select((d)=>d));
        return childss;// wrong..and cant compile
    }
}
```

How to write a query to get all the childs in one IEnumerable collection without using foreach.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
collection.SelectMany(a => a.ListChild)
```

But it will be IEnumerable of Child not IEnumerable of Parent is it ok?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use SelectMany, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Child> GetMethod()
{
    List<Parent> collection = new List<Parent>();
    //// added multiple items of collection with childs.

    return collection.SelectMany(i => i.ListChild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of `GetMethod` to `IEnumerable<Child>`